# Configuring SPF/DKIM/DMARC for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have a Google Apps Script attached to a spreadsheet, and it uses MailApp.SendMail().

```
   MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {
     noReply: true,
     htmlBody: htmlBody,
     name: emailFromName,
     replyTo: replyToEmailAddress,
     cc: ccEmailAddress
     });
```

I am running this from an account under my own domain *myowndomain.com*  I'm using gmail to manage the email from this domain.

I have SPF and DKIM configured and they work in general.  My DMARC is currently set to Quarantine, but I want to move it to Reject.

If I send mail from my personal outbox, either through gmail or another mail client through IMAP, everything is fine.  SPF, DKIM and DMARC all pass.

However, any mail that is sent from the script passes SPF but fails DMARC.  I don't think that DKIM is being triggered.  From what I've read it's because the SPF check is from google's domain and the DMARC is from *myowndomain.com*.

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of blahblah@maestro.bounces.google.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender)

dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=myowndomain.com
```

I have to believe that other people have done this and that there's a solution.

Is there a way to configure either the script or my DMARC/DKIM/SPF records so that they pass and my script-generated messages don't end up in spam?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider reporting this as an issue

Comment: Hello @Brad! Could you please share the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using so that we can better help you? And please remember to remove or anonymize any private information.

Comment: Hi Jacques-Guzel.  Thank you for the help and for the suggestion.  I didn't include any code because I believe it's a configuration problem as opposed to a code problem.  I just added the code snippet, basically the one line of code, based on your feedback though.

Comment: Hi Brad, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: You can check for yourself by viewing the raw email header. For example, here's one that failed while sending from `MailApp.sendEmail()`: `dkim=pass header.i=@your-domain.20221208.gappssmtp.com header.s=20221208; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=maestro.bounces.google.com; dmarc=fail(p=QUARANTINE) header.from=your-domain;` -- my hunch is you also have a DKIM/DMARC misalignment. [More info](https://easydmarc.com/blog/why-is-dmarc-failing/)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without knowing your DKIM settings but from this info, it seems that your SPF setup is working correctly while your DKIM check is failing. You need both for DMARC reject policy to work when you already have DKIM setup.

DKIM relies on a key pair (one public key and one private key) that the sending email server needs to have access to. Public key is easy because it is available from your DNS. Private key is tricky though.

Although your sending email services (Gmail and Google Apps) are both offered by the same company (i.e. Google), you need to treat them as if they are totally seperate email services because as far as I know, Google does not share private DKIM keys between these different email services of theirs.

It means you need to get the private DKIM key from your Gmail settings and enter it into Google Apps settings for your domain to be used by your script that is running in Google Apps.

If this is not possible (because Google might not provide the private DKIM keys that are generated by Gmail), you need to generate your own DKIM key pair and enter them in both Gmail and Google Apps to be used as the ONLY set of DKIM keys for your domain.

Comment: Thank you Amir for the detailed explanation.  I'm able to get the DKIM key for my domain, but I don't see an obvious place to install it into my Google Apps Script project.  I will search a little bit more.  Hopefully there is a setting for it.